# Model Input/output as ports

Tags: java, fractals

I have a school assignment to model a simple equation calculator using Fractal. The assignment has two parts.
1. as reusable COTS components
2. as architectural components (described by their input and output ports)

I managed to make the first part of the assignment but I can't figure out how to model a class with the input/output as ports.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how does 'a simple equation calculator using Fractal' work?

Comment: Well..Fractal isn't used for such small projects. We got this just to get along with Fractal and learn how to use it and all. More info about Fractal is here: http://fractal.ow2.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with contracts in term of:

- provided operations
- required operations
- properties (parametrization)

An operation may be an event (sent/received), a service (client/server) or a data (read/wrote).

You may read more about components from [OMG CCM](http://www.omg.org/spec/CCM/), but only for the concepts, not the implementation (heavy).